# simple python file write (mind blank)

Tags: python, file-handling

how do i go about checking if the first line of a file is occupied?

```
f = open('whatever.txt','w')
f.write('first line')
f.close()
f = open('whatever.txt','w')
f.write('second line')
f.close()
```

the second line just overwrites.

thanks!

Comment: Check the documentation for what the second `open` parameter (`'w'`) does.

Comment: oh, silly me -.- thankyou chris!

Comment: It is good for a beginner to directly start with the most pythonic way of doing stuff. So do `with open('...') as f:` line break indent `f.write(...)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `'a'` as your mode parameter the second time, so that it appends instead of overwrites. See the [`open()`` built-in function's documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open).

Answer (score 1):

The 'w' opens the file in write mode.  Use 'a' for append mode.